# Node.JS, Socket IO: Same Origin Policy error

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am having an hard time making server and client interact.

Here is the relevant code:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var io = require('socket.io');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8888');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});


app.use(express.static('./public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('/index.html')
});


var server = http.createServer(app)
io = io.listen(server); 


server.listen(8000);
```

The website loads the io.js script with:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

If I remove the port number I get a plain not found error and undefined io.

However, I get the following error, in Chrome:

```
GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1441274392959-0 

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1441274392959-0. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

In Firefox:

```
GET XHR http://localhost/socket.io/ [HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 2ms]

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1441275119628-17. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

Searching for the Cross-Origin error, I tried a couple of sulutions:

- The setHeader section I used in the code,
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21622564 tried on app, server and io.

Neither of them worked, and I don't understand why.

Can someone help me sort this out?
Thanks.

Comment: What does your client code look like? You're trying to connect to port `80` whereas your server is being served on port `8000`. You're also allowing CORS to `http://localhost:8888`, which makes no sense since your server is on `8000`.

Comment: Sorry, where are you getting these port numbers from? I point my browser to localhost:8000 and did not specify port 8888 for cors anywhere. Shouldn't the app.use line set cors to the port being used by app? Client connects like this: var socket = io.connect("/");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i thinks its because your ports are different

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8888');
```

and

```
server = server.listen(8000)
```

Comment: try this in your headers, just to be sure: (this would allow all calls, so remove the old one and check)
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();

Answer (score 0):

You can set the CORS header on your server like so :

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen( ... );
io.set("origins", "*:*");
```

Please note that in a production environment you should replace the wildcard with expected origins

Comment: io.set("origins", "*:*");
   ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Seems, you need change `listen` from `socket.io` to `server`. You add cors policy to your express listener so port must be listened by http `server` itself

```
server = require('http').Server(app);

io = require('socket.io')(server);
server = server.listen(8000)
```

Comment: change client code, now it's connecting to `http://localhost/socket.io/`, but needs to connect `http://localhost:8000/socket.io/`.
Like that: `var socket = io('http://localhost:8000/');`. And your headers must be without port `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost'`